# How can I create a custom home-screen replacement application for Android?

Tags: android, launcher, homescreen

How do I create a home-screen replacement application? Is there any information about the home-screen application available?

Can any application be a home-screen by just registering it with a `CATEGORY_HOME` intent?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Writing your own home screen application is possible. It is called the Launcher.

You can get the source code of the default Android Launcher via [Git](http://git-scm.com/).

The project URL is:

> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git

You can get the source code like this:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git
```

That will create a directory called *Launcher2* for you. Now you can get cracking and create your custom launcher.

*<sub>If you need help with using Git then checkout Git's [documentation section](http://git-scm.com/documentation).</sub>*

Comment: Don't forget to take a look at the source code of ADW Launcher as well: http://code.google.com/p/adw-launcher-android/

Comment: This question specifically asks if an app could register for a specific intent - if it's complex, I can understand the sample code, but how complex can it be?  Can someone just describe the intent and its requirements?

Comment: Which obviously makes my answer wrong. Makes sense. How about checking out the code and finding out?

Answer (score 36):

The specific Intent to make your activity the Home screen is:

```
<activity....>
<!-- Put this filter inside the activity to make it the Home screen -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Very simple. This is all I needed to know.