# How to create custom home screen

Tags: android, eclipse

I've downloaded the source for both google's default home screen and adw.  I created a project in Eclipse and used those sources.  However, I can not compile the code as there are quite a few errors.  Does anyone know how to do this correctly?  Do I need to add all of the google code to my project?
(I asked the same question in another thread, [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666771/how-to-create-a-custom-home-screen-replacement-application-on-android) )

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

> I've downloaded the source for both google's default home screen and adw.

What is "adw"?

> Does anyone know how to do this correctly?

The Home application in the Android open source project can only be built as part of a firmware image. It is not designed to be compiled just using the SDK. There is a sample Home application in your SDK, though, that builds with the SDK.

So, if your goal is to create a replacement home screen standalone app, use the Home app in your SDK as a starting point. If your goal is to create replacement firmware, download the entire firmware and build it that way.