# Removing icons from Android desktop

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am currently working on an application that is supposed to configure several devices running Android 3.0 and 3.1 connected to the workstation. The task at hand requires that we remove all of the icons on the desktop and put the needed ones on it instead.
So the question is - is there an option of programmatically locating and removing icons from Android desktop?
Any workaround is acceptable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

At this time I know only one way: develop your own "Home Screen" application. If you like this way, see [How to create a custom home-screen replacement application on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666771/how-to-create-a-custom-home-screen-replacement-application-on-android)

Comment: A plausible idea, but I suspect this should require user interaction to set as the home application even if you accomplish its installation via adb and so avoid that user confirmation dialog for simple installation.

Comment: Yes, user should select home screen application, and do it every time  pressing the "home" button until she/he selects a certain home application as a Default one.

Answer (score 0):

"Configuring" a device will likely require a number of operations which android and its default apps are designed to only permit a live user to accomplish.

The well-engineered means of doing this would be to flash an update.zip that accomplishes the desired changes, however this requires either the vendor signing keys or an unlocked recovery system, plus knowledge of the way the default apps store their private data.

On a rooted device it's probably also possible to accomplish these changes on a running system, or at least a booted one after stopping the android runtime and then restart it when done.