# android source code for home screen application

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a custom home-screen replacement application for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666771/how-can-i-create-a-custom-home-screen-replacement-application-for-android)

What is the name of the application which appears when you press *Home* button? PhoneApplication?

Where would I find it in the source code? I need it because I want to see how items are dragged so smooth on the screen.

Comment: Never mind my answer, this has been answered far better in [How can I create a custom home-screen replacement application for Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666771/how-can-i-create-a-custom-home-screen-replacement-application-for-android) , including a reference to the stock launcher's source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a Launcher, and it's not necessarily the same app everywhere. This might be of interest - a (modified) stock launcher including the source code: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=538871

See also this for inspiration: http://code.google.com/p/android-launcher-plus/

Answer (score 1):

In **android-sdk samples** also you will find one application named **Home**. this is also a launcher application., but its not much implemented, if you interested check it once.

You can get good launcher source code here

[Modified Launcher](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=538871)