# How to have the revolving icon effect?

Tags: android

[image]

You see the icons are in a revolving manner. How to achieve this on Android? Is it through OpenGL or can there be some other easier implementation.. This has been bugging me from months together and I just need a pointer or a breakthrough code. A tutorial would be of awesome help...Please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`project 3D Carousel`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel), you can get it and Since the screenshot seems to be a customized Home Screen, so you have to provide your own [customized Home Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3666849/593709),

Comment: Hi Adil, I had a look at the links.....The carousel effect project has a lot of trignometry.....Difficult to understand for a new bee like me....If you could help me on that....I know am asking for a lot..;

Answer (score 1):

Google released a carousel example with source code as part of the "Designing Android UIs for Phones and Tablets" session at Google I/O 2011. You get the source [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip&can=2&q=). It uses [Renderscript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html) to create the 3D effect.