# Using an Android tablet as "input device"

Tags: android

I'm looking for some help from developers who are know android development.  We have a client who wants to use an Android tablet as a means of collecting data when someone walks into their office.  The problem is that they don't want any of the background functions or access to the net on the device (it's there to log people in so it should not move from that function with out some other credentials to "unlock" the device.)

With apple I know you can lock the screen on to a page/app  but not sure about android?  Can't find any thing online that would tell me it can be done on android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Android you can replace the launcher (home screen) app, and if that app doesn't give you access to launching other things, then you cannot do other things. The first time you press the home key after installing another launcher candidate, Android asks you which home screen application to run (the original or your new one) and allows you to set your answer as the default, eliminating the question in the future.

Comment: Your fast!  Would you happen to know where some directions are to change that home screen would be?  Does the device need to be rooted?

Comment: The Android SDK includes a launcher project, and you can see some more details at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666771/how-can-i-create-a-custom-home-screen-replacement-application-for-android. No, device rooting is not required for this.

Comment: Note that from your description, you probably will not be interested much in that sample project, except for one thing: the AndroidManifest entries. You will want your own Activity to be the home screen, but you might not want to do anything similar to what a normal launcher does.

Comment: thanks everyone... OK so I assume that has to be coded directly on a device?  Meaning setting of the home screen can't be done through an app correct?

Comment: To set the home screen directly though an app you would need permissions that are not normally available (unless you've got a custom ROM or are a device OEM). Once the app is installed though, just press the home button on your device and "installation" will just be a matter of checking the option to remember your choice and selecting your new home screen replacement.