# Block access to playstore in android?

Tags: android, permissions

I am trying to build a simple Parental Control App. I would like to know if it is possible to set the user to enter a password before he can install an app , either from the play store or
from running apk files.

Just pointing me in the right direction would be really helpful. Right now i am quiet clueless
on where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider creating your own home screen launcher. Following post have some suggestion for creating your own launcher:

[How can I create a custom home-screen replacement application for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666771/how-can-i-create-a-custom-home-screen-replacement-application-for-android)

And following is one of the app that implement the parental contorl using the home launcher option:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiddoware.kidsplace&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5raWRkb3dhcmUua2lkc3BsYWNlIl0.

Comment: The idea of writing a complete home screen is very interesting. But i dont think i am quiet ready for that yet.Perhaps if i check if the process related to play store has been started and intercept it. Something like a broadcast reciver. Do you think it is possibe.