# change application visibility according to user's choice in android

Tags: android

Hi I am developing an application to show/hide application according to user's choice.In my application, it will display all the applications installed on the device and there is check boxes for all the application listing . If the user select a Check box then that application will not show to the menu if already hidden then it will show, when the user presses the OK button. Is there any way to show/hide the application from android device.Can anybody tell me a way to solve this problem.

Comment: i just want to hide/show installed application in the home screen according to user's choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just create your own launcher/homescreen activity. Android is perfect for creating this kind of thing.

Refer to this question:

[How can I create a custom home-screen replacement application for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666771/how-can-i-create-a-custom-home-screen-replacement-application-for-android)

Comment: can you please give me sample app that hide application

Comment: done. just 5 seconds ago.