# How can I edit Android's application menu?

Tags: android

I would like to edit the application menu in Android (where all apps and widgets are displayed).

Like this:

[image]

I would like to create an app where you can select how the icons (applications) are shown in this menu. I'm not sure if it is even called "application menu" so I'm having some trouble to find some more info about this matter.

If anyone could help me find a way to override the original layout or point me in the right direction, that would be awesome!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are showing in the pic, is called a Launcher.

You can create a custom Launcher. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666771/how-can-i-create-a-custom-home-screen-replacement-application-for-android) to get started.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's hard to search for something if you're not sure what you're searching for :)

Comment: Good, don't forget to mark the question as answwered, by clicking the check on the left