# How to move the app icon to a folder in the launcher menu?

Tags: android, icons, directory, launcher

Is it possible to move an app icon to a newly created folder or an already existing folder inside the launcher menu programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home Screen Launcher apps are just that: apps. They are written by device manufacturers and third-party developers. If the creator provided an API to programmatically add an app into a folder then sure, but otherwise no standard API exists in Android. You are free the build a launcher app without the folder metaphor or widgets or multiple screens.

Comment: So isn't there any specific standard for developing the APIs that different vendors follow to develop their stock launchers?

Comment: Not to my knowledge - everyone is free to do what they want or don't want as an Android app so long as minimally say the app is a home screen launcher: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666771/how-can-i-create-a-custom-home-screen-replacement-application-for-android